# JSP: jstl core CONDITIONS with java.lang.Byte[]

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have this piece of code in my JSP in my spring MVC application deployed in a WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0. I am using **jstl-1.2**

```
2-> [${item.companyLogo}]
3-> [${empty item.companyLogo}]
4-> [${item.companyLogo eq null}]
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${empty item.companyLogo} ">
IS EMPTY
<img src="${contextPath}/images/devices-logo.gif"  />
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
NOT EMPTY
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

also tried

```
<c:when test="${empty item.companyLogo == true} ">
```

But in the screen I see these:

```
2-> [] 
3-> [true] 
4-> [true] 

NOT EMPTY
```

If I try to check the length with `${item.companyLogo.length}`
I got this error:

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "length"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
        at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.toInteger(ArrayELResolver.java:378)
        at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:198)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.ELHelper.evaluate(ELHelper.java:32)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._result.__productcategoryresult._jspService(__productcategoryresult.java:330)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:478)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:367)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:573)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:480)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:347)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:204)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._template.__template._jsp__tag10(__template.java:659)
```

This is the type of the property `companyLogo`

```
Byte[] companyLogo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSTL function `length` instead:

- Import also at the beginning of your page the function taglib:

  ```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
  ```
- Then to get the length:

  ```
  ${fn:length(item.companyLogo)}
  ```